# proxy pac file in windows 7/ie10

Tags: proxy, internet-explorer-10, pac

I have set the proxy file as shown below:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    return  "PROXY 10.10.10.10:8080";
}
```

Nothing exists at 10.10.10.10. In IE10/Windows 7 x64, I have disabled "Automatically Detect Settings" and "use Proxy Server for your LAN" under Lan Settings in IE.

The browser is just disregarding the PAC file and going to the websites direct, as they are being loaded in the browser.

Things I have tried with unsuccessful results: 
1. Checked Proxy file path by directly putting it in browser URL field. It is downloadable through browser.
2. Double slash in the file path for pac file
3. Moving the pac file in different locations
4. Google Chorme with double slashes

Anything I am missing here?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this page

http://kb.k12usa.com/Knowledgebase/Proxy-Auto-Detect-WPAD-Issues-With-IE-Windows-7

> Windows 7 added a feature when using Proxy Auto Detect (WPAD) with Internet Explorer, where if the computer fails to detect the proxy settings once, it will not try again.  This is a problem if you then later configure your network to support Proxy Auto Detect.  This article explains how to disable this new feature, and allow WPAD to work correctly.

To prevent Windows from tracking which network support WPAD, you need to make a simple registry change:

1. Click the Start button, and in the search field, type in "regedit", then select "regedit.exe" from the list of results
2. Navigate through the tree to "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Wpad"
3. Once you have the "Wpad" folder selected, right click in the right pane, and click on "New -> DWORD (32-Bit Value)"
4. Name this new value "WpadOverride"
5. Double click the new "WpadOverride" value to edit it
6. In the "Value data" field, replace the "0" with a "1", then click "OK"
7. Reboot the computer